# avro-tools complain: Failed to load class “org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder” - Or - How to properly give a classpath in java

Tags: java, slf4j, avro-tools

Please consider this before closing this question as well:

> It doesn't help me, getting solutions for websphere etc. I run
> commandline tools, not a server.
>
> So if you think it should help, please tell me how, because I don't
> understand how it could possibly help. Thank you.

When running avro-tools I get

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I assume these are just warnings and it's not so important to fix it, as the results I get seem correct.

Reading not all but a lot of similar questions here I found that I require

> slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar.

I downloaded `slf4j-nop-1.7.3.jar` and run avro tools like so:

```
CLASSPATH=/myhome/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.3.jar java -jar /myhome/lib/avro-tools-1.10.0.jar
```

I also tried

```
java  -cp /myhome/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.3.jar -jar /myhome/lib/avro-tools-1.10.0.jar
```

but get no difference.

I'm not a java programmer and do not intend to become one. I'm just using pre-compiled binaries.

Can you please tell me how to fix the warning?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found it.

1. Check for the main class in META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
2. Call the main class like so:

```
java  -cp /myhome/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.3.jar:/myhome/lib/avro-tools-1.10.0.jar org.apache.avro.tool.Main
```

Maybe this is all logical, but I beg to differ…

Comment: Also consider `java -cp '/myhome/lib/*' org.apache.avro.tool.Main`. Note that you will get no log output if you use the "nop / no operation" jar. Consider using the simple jar to get log output to system err.